# Java String Calculator

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in Java which takes input in the form of a string and does a simple '+' and '-' operation.

Single digit inputs work but my problem is when i try to implement this for double digit

input string is: 5+20+5+11 
list 1  = [5, 20, 2, 0, 5, 11, 1]
list 2  = [+, +, +]
Answer:27

I need to find a way where after storing [5] in list1 how i can add [5,20] instead of [5,20,2,0] which the current code is doing.

```java
public int calC(String input) {
        int len = input.length();
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if ((input.charAt(i) != '+') && (input.charAt(i) != '-')) {
                // check if the number is double-digit
                if ((i + 1 <= len - 1)) {
                    if ((input.charAt(i + 1) != '+')&& (input.charAt(i + 1) != '-')) {
                        String temp = "";
                        temp = temp + input.charAt(i) + input.charAt(i + 1);
                        int tempToInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                        // adding the double digit number
                        list1.add(tempToInt);
                    }
                    // add single digit number
                    list1.add(input.charAt(i) - '0');
                }
            } else {
                // adding the symbols
                list2.add(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        int result = 0;
        result = result + (int) list1.get(0);
        for (int t = 0; t < list2.size(); t++) {
            char oper = (char) list2.get(t);
            if (oper == '+') {
                result = result + (int) list1.get(t + 1);

            } else if (oper == '-') {
                result = result - (int) list1.get(t + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Edit: working version 
@Ker p pag thanks for the updated methods
input string is: 5+20+5+11
[5, 20, 5, 11]
[+, +, +]
Answer:41
I'll need to try to implement this with stack as suggested but the current version works

```
static boolean isDigit(char check) {
    if (Character.isDigit(check)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static int calC(String input) {

    int len = input.length();
    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((i + 1 <= len - 1)) {
            if (isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1))) {
                String temp = input.charAt(i) + "" + input.charAt(i + 1);
                int toInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                list1.add(toInt);
                i = i+1;
            } else if (isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
                list1.add(input.charAt(i)- '0');
            } else {
                list2.add(input.charAt(i));
            }

        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    result = result + (int) list1.get(0);
    for (int t = 0; t < list2.size(); t++) {
        char oper = (char) list2.get(t);
        if (oper == '+') {
            result = result + (int) list1.get(t + 1);

        } else if (oper == '-') {
            result = result - (int) list1.get(t + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why do not you use stack to make your life easier?

Comment: stack would be a great implementation for this operation.

Comment: input is  5+20+5+11  but in your list [5, 20, 2, 0, 5, 11, 1?

Comment: yes @Kerppag, hence i'm trying to find a way i can add [5,20,5,11] instead of the current elements in the list

Comment: @tmax what do you mean ?

Comment: @KickButtowski i think even if i used stack id still have the same issue for double digits i may end up with duplicate entries for the double digits..

Comment: @tmax how come ? it seems your over-complicated your life. If you like I can post up an example so you can see no duplicate

Comment: @tmax *input string is: 5+20+5+11*, what the result does you want? 41 or 27?

Comment: @tmax for love of Moses you are checking everything char by char. use stack and make yourself happy

Comment: @KickButtowski so currently i am getting  [5, 20, 2, 0, 5, 11, 1] entered into the list, if i used stack and pushed it to the stack if i use the same conditions in my first for-loop it would still push [5, 20, 2, 0, 5, 11, 1] into the stack...

Comment: @tmax could you add your stack version of your code to your question?

Comment: @ANyarThar i'm looking for 41

Comment: Your problem is not "how i can add [5,20] instead of [5,20,2,0]", but "how can I fix my reading procedure so that it gives me [5,20,5,11]".  For that, it's OK to increment variable i inside the reading loop.  It's better to also approach the problem assuming any-length numbers (at least within int range), rather than coding specifically for just 1 or 2 digit.

Comment: @racraman you're right, so i tried the increment approach after list1.add(tempToInt); i = i+1; but then i get [5, 20, 0, 5, 11, 1], if i use i+2 i get index out of bounds

Comment: @Kerppag i updated the code with your methods it works thank you.

Comment: i undelete my post. xD

Comment: Are you just ignoring the other answers? At least notice the fact you can do `Character.isDigit(c)` rather than a massive `if ||` block

Comment: @weston thank you, i'm sorry but im still trying to fix and see if the first implementation works fine, im also trying the other answers.

Comment: didnt know that Character has isDigit() method.ahaa i've created my own xD

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code:

```
    String a = "5+20-15+8";
    System.out.println(a);
    String operators[]=a.split("[0-9]+");
    String operands[]=a.split("[+-]");
    int agregate = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<operands.length;i++){
        if(operators[i].equals("+"))
            agregate += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
        else 
            agregate -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(agregate);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot

Comment: Nice solution - But how do we handle `-ve` numbers? For example - `"-5+20-15+8"` - Only when the 1st digit is `-ve`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the result `41` for input string `"5+20+5+11"`,
why not use `ScriptEngineManager` with `JavaScript` engine,

```
public double calC(String input) {
    int result = 0;
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();    
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");        
    return (Double)engine.eval(input);
}
```

But note that the return type is `double` here.

If you want only `int` as return type in this case, try with this

```
return new BigDecimal(engine.eval(input).toString()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about this:

```
public class InlineParsing {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String input = "5-2+20+5+11-10";
        input = input.replace(" ","");

        String parsedInteger = "";
        String operator = "";
        int aggregate = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            char c = input.charAt(i); 
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                parsedInteger += c;
            }
            if (!Character.isDigit(c) || i == input.length()-1){
                int parsed = Integer.parseInt(parsedInteger);
                if (operator == "") {
                    aggregate = parsed;
                }
                else {
                    if (operator.equals("+")) {
                        aggregate += parsed;
                    }else if (operator.equals("-")){
                        aggregate -= parsed;
                    }
                }

                parsedInteger ="";
                operator = ""+c;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of " + input+":\r\n" + aggregate);
    }
}
```

It's basically a state machine that traverses over each char.

Iterate over each char:

1. if current char is a digit, add to current number buffer
2. if current char is not a digit or we're parsing the last digit

   1. if an operator has been parsed use that to add the newly parsed number to the sum
      if no operator has been parsed, set sum to current parsed number
   2. clear current number buffer
   3. store current char as operator

Answer (score 0):

for storing the input to the list you could try this snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {

        // make a method
        // check if current character is number || check if current
        // character is number and the next character
        if (isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1))) {

            list.add(input.charAt(i) +""+ input.charAt(i + 1));

        } else if (isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {

            list.add(input.charAt(i));

        }else{
            operator.add(input.charAt(i));
        }

    }


//check if it is a number
public boolean isDigit(char input){
if(input == '1' ||
input == '2' ||
input == '3' ||
input == '4' ||
input == '5' ||
input == '6' ||
input == '7' ||
input == '8' ||
input == '9' ||
input == '0')
    return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that stack is the best solution,but still giving an alternative way
of doing this.

```
   String input = "5+20+11+1";
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
   char[] ch = input.toCharArray();
   for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
   {
       if(ch[i]!='+')
       { 

           sb.append(ch[i]);
       }else
       {

           list2.add(ch[i]);
           list1.add(Integer.valueOf(sb.toString()));
           sb.setLength(0); 
       }
   }
   if(sb.length()!=0)
       list1.add(Integer.valueOf(sb.toString()));
   System.out.println(list1.size());
   for(Integer i:list1)
   {
       System.out.println("values"+i);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could advise you to use [Exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/). It is easy to understand as you can see from the following example code:

```
Expression e = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
    .variables("x", "y")
    .build()
    .setVariable("x", 2.3)
    .setVariable("y", 3.14);
double result = e.evaluate();
```

Especially for the case of using more complex expression this could be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int myCal() {
 String[] digits = {
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5"
 };
 String[] ops = {
  "+",
  "+",
  "+",
  "-"
 };
 int temp = 0;
 int res = 0;
 int count = ops.length;

 for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {

  res = Integer.parseInt(digits[i]);
  if (i != 0 && count != 0) {
   count--;
   switch (ops[i - 1]) {
    case "+":
     temp = Math.addExact(temp, res);
     break;

    case "-":
     temp = Math.subtractExact(temp, res);
     break;
    case "*":
     temp = Math.multiplyExact(temp, res);
     break;
    case "/":
     temp = Math.floorDiv(temp, res);
     break;
   }
  }
 }
 return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code that I created using array only. I also tried several arithmetic problems also your given problem.

Please see also the comments within the method.

```
public static String Calculator(String str) {
    // will get all numbers and store it to `numberStr`
    String numberStr[] = str.replaceAll("[+*/()-]+"," ").split(" ");
    // will get all operators and store it to `operatorStr`
    String operatorStr[] = str.replaceAll("[0-9()]+","").split("");

    int total = Integer.parseInt(numberStr[0]);

    for (int i=0; i<operatorStr.length; i++) {
        switch (operatorStr[i]) {
            case "+" :
                total += Integer.parseInt(numberStr[i+1]);
                break;
            case "-" :
                total -= Integer.parseInt(numberStr[i+1]);
                break;
            case "*" :
                total *= Integer.parseInt(numberStr[i+1]);
                break;
            case "/" :
                total /= Integer.parseInt(numberStr[i+1]);
                break;
        }

        if(i+2 >= operatorStr.length) continue; // if meets the last operands already
        numberStr[i+1] = String.valueOf(total);

    }
    return String.valueOf(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> listOfOpertionsCharFORM = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Character> listOfNumbersCharFORM = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM = new ArrayList<>();


    int Total = 0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    System.out.print("Please enter your math equation :");
    input = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("string is : " + input);
    separator();


    char[] convertAllToChar = input.toCharArray();

    for (char inputToChar : convertAllToChar) {
        System.out.println("convertAllToChar     " + inputToChar);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

        if (convertAllToChar[i] == '+') {
            listOfOpertionsCharFORM.add(convertAllToChar[i]);
        }
        if (convertAllToChar[i] == '-') {
            listOfOpertionsCharFORM.add(convertAllToChar[i]);
        }
        if (convertAllToChar[i] == '*') {
            listOfOpertionsCharFORM.add(convertAllToChar[i]);
        }
        if (convertAllToChar[i] == '/') {
            listOfOpertionsCharFORM.add(convertAllToChar[i]);
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(convertAllToChar[i])) {
            listOfNumbersCharFORM.add(convertAllToChar[i]);
        }


    }
    separator();
    for (Character aa : listOfOpertionsCharFORM) {
        System.out.println("list Of Operations Char FORM     " + aa);
    }
    separator();
    for (Character aa : listOfNumbersCharFORM) {
        System.out.println("list Of Numbers Char FORM       " + aa);

    }
    separator();

    for (Character aa : listOfNumbersCharFORM) {
        if (aa == '0') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(0);
        if (aa == '1') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(1);
        if (aa == '2') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(2);
        if (aa == '3') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(3);
        if (aa == '4') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(4);
        if (aa == '5') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(5);
        if (aa == '6') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(6);
        if (aa == '7') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(7);
        if (aa == '8') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(8);
        if (aa == '9') listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.add(9);

    }

    for (Integer aaa : listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM) {
        System.out.println("list Of Numbers INTEGER FORM       " + aaa);
    }


    separator();
    separator();
    separator();


    System.out.print(listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM);

    System.out.print(listOfOpertionsCharFORM);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();


    if (listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.size() == (listOfOpertionsCharFORM.size() + 1)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfOpertionsCharFORM.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i   :" + i);
            if (listOfOpertionsCharFORM.get(i) == '+') if (i == 0) {
                Total = Total + listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i) + listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            } else {
                Total = Total + listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            }
            if (listOfOpertionsCharFORM.get(i) == '-') if (i == 0) {
                Total = Total + listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i) - listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            } else {
                Total = Total - listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            }
            if (listOfOpertionsCharFORM.get(i) == '*') if (i == 0) {
                Total = Total + listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i) * listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            } else {
                Total = Total * listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            }
            if (listOfOpertionsCharFORM.get(i) == '/') if (i == 0) {
                Total = Total + listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i) / listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            } else {
                Total = Total / listOfNumbersINTEGERFORM.get(i + 1);
                System.out.println("total   : " + Total);
                separatorShort();
            }

        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("*********###############**********");
        System.out.println("** your input not correct input **");
        System.out.println("*********###############**********");

    }

    System.out.println("*** Final Answer *** :  " + Total);

}

public static void separator() {
    System.out.println("___________________________________");
}

public static void separatorShort() {
    System.out.println("_____________");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).